# How do I fix a CAW Moveset glitch in WWE 2K14 Online?

Tags: wwe-2k14

I play WWE 2K14 on Xbox Live, and for some reason, when I play Xbox Live with my Created Superstar, the moveset I created will not work.

When I fight, it has the starting moveset that the game gives to every starting CAW.

If you know, how do I fix this glitch?

Answer (score -2):

I've been able to fix this issue by copying a moveset from a CAW that I know to be working properly, then going back and editing those moves as appropriate.